# Timeout exception for node assignment. Call: describeTopics in Managed Apache flink application using Kafka as source

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-flink, aws-msk

I have created Managed Apache flink streaming application with

1. flink version - 1.15.2
2. flink-connector-kafka connector - 1.15.4.
3. Apache Kafka version 3.5.1
   In application code, I am just reading message from kafka topic and insert into MySQL table using JDBC connector. When run the Flink application in AWS console it goes into RUNNING state but giving following error:

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: Kafka Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed' (operator cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:556)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:329)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to list subscribed topic partitions due to 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.checkPartitionChanges(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:234)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$4(ExecutorNotifier.java:133)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get metadata for topics [template_insights].
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.TopicListSubscriber.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(TopicListSubscriber.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$5(ExecutorNotifier.java:130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=describeTopics, deadlineMs=1703573019703, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1703573019805) timed out at 1703573019705 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:44)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=describeTopics, deadlineMs=1703573019703, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1703573019805) timed out at 1703573019705 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeTopics
```

Here is my kafka source creation code:

```
Properties sourceProperties = KinesisAnalyticsRuntime.getApplicationProperties().get("KafkaSource");
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers((String) sourceProperties.get("bootstrap.servers"))
                .setTopics((String) sourceProperties.get("topic"))
                .setGroupId("kafka-replication")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .setProperty("partition.discovery.interval.ms", "20000")
                .setProperty("metadata.max.age.ms", "90000") // Adjust as needed
                .setProperty("request.timeout.ms", "80000") // Adjust as needed
                .setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
                .setProperty("sasl.mechanism","AWS_MSK_IAM")
                .setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required aws.accessKeyId=\"mykey\" aws.secretKey=\"mysecretkey\";")
                .setProperty("sasl.client.callback.handler.class", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build();
env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
```

Can someone help me please to understand why I am getting timeout error when I run flink application?

Comment: The Flink Kafka connector for 1.15 is compatible with Kafka Clients version 2.8.1, see https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.15.4/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/pom.xml#L39 - I wouldn't be surprised if the newer versions of the Kafka Client you're using isn't compatible.